# Why do my for-in loop doesn't work? Error Handling Swift

Tags: swift, error-handling, for-in-loop

I tried a error handling function to crack the code of a safe(for example), In my thoughts the for-in loop should print all the tries which are in the array...
But the thing is that just the first String of the array gets printed and the others aren`t. Can anyone tell me where is my failure?

```
enum SafeError: Error {
    case wrongCode
    case tooMuchTries
    case safeIsOpen
}

 struct Safe {
    var safeIsclosed: Bool
    var code: String
    var maximumTries: Int
    mutating func OpenSafe(triedCodes: [String]) throws {
        guard safeIsclosed else {
            throw SafeError.safeIsOpen
        }
        for triedCode in triedCodes {
            print("Try \(triedCode)")
            
        
            guard triedCode == code else {
                throw SafeError.wrongCode
            }
        }
        guard triedCodes.count <= maximumTries else {
            throw SafeError.tooMuchTries
        }

    print("Password was correct")
        
    }
    
}
var safe = Safe(safeIsclosed: true, code: "WD1146", maximumTries: 5)

do {
    try safe.OpenSafe(triedCodes: ["DD377789", "123456", "WD1146", "112378AADD", "DDFG4567"])
} catch SafeError.safeIsOpen {
    print("Safe is already open")
} catch SafeError.tooMuchTries {
    print("Safe is closed now, your try was wrong")
} catch SafeError.wrongCode {
    print("Wrong Password")
} catch {
    print("Error")
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You `throw` on a first unsuccessfull attempt. Throwing an error lets you indicate that something unexpected happened and the normal flow of execution can’t continue. Everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `throw` from a function terminates the execution of said function immediately. This means that as soon as the first element of `triedCodes` is wrong, your function terminates because a `.wrongCode` error is thrown.

I would suggest modifying your function such that you check whether the correct code is contained in the `triedCodes` array and throw an error in case it isn't. This ensures that the whole array is checked before an error is thrown.

```
mutating func openSafe(triedCodes: [String]) throws {
    guard safeIsclosed else {
        throw SafeError.safeIsOpen
    }

    guard triedCodes.contains(code) else {
        throw SafeError.wrongCode
    }

    guard triedCodes.count <= maximumTries else {
        throw SafeError.tooMuchTries
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the first exception you are out of the loop.

Try changing the struct like this:

```
struct Safe {
var safeIsclosed: Bool
var code: String
var maximumTries: Int

func OpenSafe(triedCode: String) throws {
    guard safeIsclosed else {
        throw SafeError.safeIsOpen
    }
    print("Try \(triedCode)")
    
    guard triedCode == code else {
        throw SafeError.wrongCode
    }
}

mutating func OpenSafe(triedCodes: [String]) throws {
    guard safeIsclosed else {
        throw SafeError.safeIsOpen
    }
    for triedCode in triedCodes {
        do {
            try safe.OpenSafe(triedCode: triedCode)
        } catch SafeError.safeIsOpen {
            print("Safe is already open")
        } catch SafeError.wrongCode {
            print("Wrong Password")
        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }
    }
    guard triedCodes.count <= maximumTries else {
        throw SafeError.tooMuchTries
    }

    print("Password was correct") 
}
}
```

I cannot test it right now, so I could have syntax errors.